# Catalogsearch category filter not listing certain sub-sub categories

Tags: magento-1.8, catalogsearch

We have the following category tree:

Default Category

```
  | Shop categories

      | Sub category 1
      | Sub category 2 
      | Sub category 3

  | Sale Corner

  | Another category
```

So it's like 1 Default Category, 3 Sub categories, and the Shop Categories (which is basically a sub category) has around 20 Sub Sub categories.

When I do a catalogsearch, I want it to Search inside the Sub Sub categories.

It now only searches in the sub categories.

It shows up in the results like this:

Shop By

Categories:

Shop Categories +

Sale Corner +

Another Category +

Whatever I try; anchoring the sub sub categories and not anchoring the 3 normal sub categories, it just won't display the sub sub categories. The only thing it will show when I anchor it is the name of the Shop categories.

I only have this problem with the catalogsearch, the normal navigation works fine.

Comment: Anyone know the answer for this. i had same problem

Comment: What I did as a temporary solution was this:
I made a copy of form.mini.phtml and placed it within my template folder. Look for it inside template/catalogsearch/.

Edit the file and add:

     <label for="search"><?php echo $this->__('Search:') ?></label>
     <!-- add this underneath the Search label-->
<input type="hidden" name="cat" value=" [place id-number of category here and remove the brackets]" />

You have to find the ID of the category in which you want to search within (with the most sub-categories).