# Catalogsearch super sub categories products search not working

Tags: catalog, catalogsearch, sub-categories, search-result

I tried a lot, but I can't find a solution. In catalogsearch only showing the selected category product, it's not showing the subcategory of the selected category. I tried a lot of suggestion on google. but it wouldn't help me to out.

**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468059/magento-filter-product-collection-by-multiple-categories**

**[Catalogsearch category filter not listing certain sub-sub categories](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/201243/catalogsearch-category-filter-not-listing-certain-sub-sub-categories)**